# Load multiple radio button programmatically on winform groupbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list of string, and i would like to load all items to a radio buttons. The user will be able to select only 1 item from the radio buttons and then click continue.

Code:

```
            List<Control> radioButtons = new List<Control>();
            var cacheNames = GetCacheNames();
            //Lets load cache names to cachesRadioButtonsPanel
            foreach (var cacheName in cacheNames)
            {
                RadioButton radiobutton = new RadioButton();
                radiobutton.Name = cacheName;
                radiobutton.Text = cacheName;
                radioButtons.Add(radiobutton);
            }

            foreach (var singleControl in radioButtons)
            {
                cachesRadioButtonsGroupBox.Controls.Add(singleControl);
            }
```

The result is only the first item is visible. How come ?

- **Solution:**

  ```
          var cacheNames = GetCacheNames();
          //Lets load cache names to cachesRadioButtonsPanel
          int i=20; //pixel location
          foreach (var cacheName in cacheNames)
          {
              RadioButton radiobutton = new RadioButton();
              radiobutton.Name = cacheName;
              radiobutton.Text = cacheName;
              radiobutton.Location = new Point(10, i);
              cachesRadioButtonsGroupBox.Controls.Add(radiobutton);
              i += 20;
          }
          cachesRadioButtonsGroupBox.Height = i + 10;
  ```

Comment: Ahem, they re all there, just stacked one on the top of the other. You need to set the Location property to see them

Comment: @steve thanks added solution, hope this silly question will be removed.

Comment: I cant delete it - since he answered.. question with answer cannot be deleted. I flagged it.

Comment: Ops I see it now, just for curiosity, why two loops? The groupbox add could be moved inside at the end of the first loop.

Comment: The code is not final, i know no 2 loops is required, I just wanted to validate during debug that i actually have 12 different items in the list - since i only saw 1 visual

Answer (score 2):

They are all on the same spot. You need to set the [Location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.control.location(v=vs.110).aspx) property to have them on different spots on your Form.

```
        List<Control> radioButtons = new List<Control>();
        var cacheNames = GetCacheNames();
        var location = new Point(0,0);
        //Lets load cache names to cachesRadioButtonsPanel
        foreach (var cacheName in cacheNames)
        {
            RadioButton radiobutton = new RadioButton();
            radiobutton.Name = cacheName;
            radiobutton.Text = cacheName;
            radiobutton.Location = location;
            radioButtons.Add(radiobutton);

            location.Y = location.Y + radiobutton.Height;
        }

        foreach (var singleControl in radioButtons)
        {
            cachesRadioButtonsGroupBox.Controls.Add(singleControl);
        }
```